# Directive is changing parent disable attribute

Tags: angular

I have a button, and a directive.

The button can be disabled by the template himself (depending on the parameters) and also by the directive (it disabled in case of doubleclick)

Here code exemple =>

```
    <button mat-button *ngFor="let button of buttons" 
        [disabled]="(button.type === 'confirmation') && IsAnyConfirmationInvalid()">
        {{button.text}}
    </button>
```

Basically, here the button is disable IF it's type confirmation, and the confirmation is invalid. It works

I then add my directive

```
        <button mat-button *ngFor="let button of buttons" 
            [disabled]="(button.type === 'confirmation') && IsAnyConfirmationInvalid()"
            appThrottleClick 
            (click)="button.action();" 
            [throttleTime]="1000">
            {{button.text}}
        </button>
```

Directive code =>

```
export class ThrottleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @HostBinding('attr.disabled') disabled : boolean;

    @Input() 
    throttleTime = 1000;

    @Output() 
    throttleClick = new EventEmitter();

    private clicks = new Subject();
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
            throttleTime(this.throttleTime)
        ).subscribe(e => {
            this.throttleClick.emit(e)
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.disabled = true;
        this.clicks.next(event);
        setTimeout(() => {this.disabled = null;}, this.throttleTime)      
    }
}
```

I want my button to be disabled if the same condition (type confirmation) is true, but also from the directive, in case I click, it must be disabled so I can't double click.

The problem is, at the moment, only the directive is considered, so my button is always enable expect when I click.

How do I make booth disable cohexist together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by using a intermediate variable =>

```
    <button mat-button *ngFor="let button of buttons" 
        appThrottleClick 
        [throttleDisabled]="(button.type === 'confirmation') && IsAnyConfirmationInvalid()"
        (throttleClick)="button.action();" 
        [throttleTime]="1000">
        {{button.text}}
    </button>
```

And

```
@HostBinding('disabled') disabled : boolean;

@Input() 
throttleTime = 1000;

@Input() 
set throttleDisabled(val : boolean) {
    console.log(val)
    this.disabled = val;
}
```